# Tracing in Guile - How to trace in Guile Scheme

Tags: scheme, trace, guile

What are the equivalents in Guile Scheme of the `(trace procedure)` and `(trace-let (bindings) body)` tracing facilities from Chez Scheme.

I've reviewed the documentation at https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Tracing-Traps.html, but I cannot figure out how to use the Guile tracing procedures from the source code file, not from the Guile REPL which may be done with `,trace (procedure application)` given previously imported module `(use-modules (system vm trace))`.

I'm interested in tracing from the source code the application of recursive procedures similar to `(trace fact1)` with the below output to the console

```
trace: (fact1 4)
trace: |  (fact1 3)
trace: |  |  (fact1 2)
trace: |  |  |  (fact1 1)
trace: |  |  |  |  (fact1 0)
trace: |  |  |  |  1
trace: |  |  |  1
trace: |  |  2
trace: |  6
trace: 24
```

Could the named let `(let name (bindings) body)` syntactic extension be traced in Guile? The need for this arises when investigating tail recursive implementations of procedures.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See add-trap-at-procedure-call! on the page https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-2.0/guile-ref/High_002dLevel-Traps.html.

An example:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (fact-iter 1 1 n))
(define (fact-iter product counter max-count)
  (if (> counter max-count)
      product
      (fact-iter (* counter product)
 (+ 1 counter)
 max-count)))
(add-trace-at-procedure-call! fact-iter)
(add-trace-at-procedure-call! factorial)
(factorial 6)
$41 = 7
$42 = 8
Trap 8: (factorial 6)
Trap 7: (fact-iter 1 1 6)
Trap 7: |  (fact-iter 1 2 6)
Trap 7: |  |  (fact-iter 2 3 6)
Trap 7: |  |  |  (fact-iter 6 4 6)
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  (fact-iter 24 5 6)
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  |  (fact-iter 120 6 6)
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  |  |  (fact-iter 720 7 6)
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  |  |  720
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  |  720
Trap 7: |  |  |  |  720
Trap 7: |  |  |  720
Trap 7: |  |  720
Trap 7: |  720
Trap 7: 720
Trap 8: 720
$43 = 720
```

factorial & fact-iter taken from SICP 1.2.1.

I don't know how to make it show  tail recursion or if this means there is no tail recursive call optimization. But it traces.